# Use exit code in if statement in Jenkins pipeline

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, exit-code, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

Here's my Jenkins pipeline where I'm trying to to run a conditional statement on the basis of previous command's exit code.

```bash
pipeline{
    agent any
    stages{
        stage('Test exitcode'){
            steps{
                script{
                    EX_CODE = sh(
                            script: 'echo hello-world',
                            returnStatus: true
                        )
                    if( env.EX_CODE == 0 ){
                        echo "Code is good with $EX_CODE"
                    }else{
                        echo "Code is Bad with $EX_CODE"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here's its output

```
Started by user Yatharth Sharma
[Pipeline] Start of Pipeline
[Pipeline] node
Running on Jenkins in /var/lib/jenkins/workspace/devops/syntax-testing-pipeline
[Pipeline] { (hide)
[Pipeline] stage
[Pipeline] { (Test exitcode)
[Pipeline] script
[Pipeline] {
[Pipeline] sh
+ echo hello-world
hello-world
[Pipeline] echo
Code is Bad with 0
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // script
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // stage
[Pipeline] }
[Pipeline] // node
[Pipeline] End of Pipeline
Finished: SUCCESS
```

I was expecting this to return `Code is good` but this prints out `Code is Bad`. Can someone help me here with a why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are assigning the `int` return of the exit code from the shell interpreter command from the `sh` step method to a variable `EX_CODE`. You then attempt to access the value from the `env` object member in the conditional as if it were an environment variable instead of a variable. You can either modify the variable to be an environment variable, or access the variable directly (simpler).

```
EX_CODE = sh(script: 'echo hello-world', returnStatus: true)
if (EX_CODE == 0) {
  echo "Code is good with ${EX_CODE}"
}
else{
  echo "Code is Bad with ${EX_CODE}"
}
```